# The Tomita-Takesaki theory for von Neumann algebras with a separating and cyclic vector by Alfons van Daele.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, functional-calculus

I am learning the theory of standard von Neumann algebras by following Chapter $10$ from the book 'Lectures on von Neumann algebras' by Strătilă and Zsidó. But I got stuck with an argument provided in [Section $6^{\circ}$](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MB3kbT-Pd0h8od82To7cBfySk4rl-7OD/view?usp=sharing) of the Chapter $10$. Let me elaborate the notations and prerequisites before posing my problems.
Let $\mathscr{M}\subseteq\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ be a von Neumann algebra which has cyclic and separating vector $\xi_0\in\mathcal{H}$. Consider the conjugate linear operator $S_0:\mathscr{M}\xi_0\ni x\xi_0\mapsto x^*\xi_0\in\mathscr{M}\xi_0\subseteq\mathcal{H};\,\mathscr{D}_{S_0}=\mathscr{M}\xi_0$. Then $S_0$ is closable and denote its closure by $S$. Consider the modular operator $\Delta=S^*S$ and the polar decomposition $S=J\Delta^{1/2}$ where $J=J^*=J^{-1}$. See [Section $1^{\circ}$](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13dX3bftGOz-OaSvTJ_C8N0mpK6TWccxp/view?usp=sharing) for the details.
Now let me recall a few results from the book which will be used later.

**Proposition 9.23:** Let $A$ and $B$ be positive self-adjoint operators in $\mathcal{H}$, such that $\text{Kernel}(A)=\text{Kernel}(B)=\{0\}$ and $\omega\in\mathbb{C},\,|\omega|=1,\,\omega\neq -1$. For any $x\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$, there exists a unique $y\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$, such that
$$\langle x\eta |\xi \rangle = \omega \langle yB^{-1/2}\eta | A^{1/2}\xi\rangle +\langle yB^{1/2}\eta | A^{-1/2}\xi\rangle ,$$
$$\xi\in\mathscr{D}_{(A^{1/2})}\cap \mathscr{D}_{(A^{-1/2})},\;\eta\in\mathscr{D}_{(B^{1/2})}\cap \mathscr{D}_{(B^{-1/2})},$$
and it is given by $y=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{{\omega}^{it-\frac{1}{2}}}{e^{\pi t}+e^{-\pi t}}A^{it}xB^{-it}dt$.

**Corollary 9.23:** Let $A$ be a positive self-adjoint operator in $\mathcal{H}$, such that $\text{Kernel}(A)=\{0\}$ and $\omega\in\mathbb{C},\,|\omega|=1,\,\omega\neq -1$. Then
$$A^{-1/2}(\omega + A^{-1})^{-1}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{{\omega}^{it-\frac{1}{2}}}{e^{\pi t} + e^{-\pi t}}A^{it}dt.$$

**Lemma $3^{\circ}$:** For $\omega\in\mathbb{C},\,|\omega|=1,\,\omega\neq -1$, we have $(\Delta +\omega)^{-1}\mathscr{M}'\xi_0\subseteq \mathscr{M}\xi_0$.

**Lemma $5^{\circ}$:** Let $x'\in\mathscr{M}'$ and $\omega\in\mathbb{C},\,|\omega|=1,\,\omega\neq -1$. Then
$$\langle x'\eta | \xi \rangle = \langle Jx^*J{\Delta}^{-1/2}\eta | {\Delta}^{1/2}\zeta\rangle + \omega\langle Jx^*J{\Delta}^{1/2}\eta | {\Delta}^{-1/2}\zeta\rangle $$
for any $\eta,\zeta\in\mathscr{D}_{{\Delta}^{1/2}}\cap \mathscr{D}_{{\Delta}^{-1/2}}$ where $x\in\mathscr{M}$ is given by $x'\xi_0=(\Delta +\omega)x\xi_0$ (by Lemma $3^{\circ}$).

Now Section $6^{\circ}$ goes as follows.
Given $x'\in\mathscr{M}'$ and $\omega\in\mathbb{C},\,|\omega|=1,\,\omega\neq -1$, we obtain the equation of Lemma $5^{\circ}$ with $x\in\mathscr{M}$ such that $x'\xi_0=(\Delta + \omega)x\xi_0$. Consider now another arbitrary $y'\in\mathscr{M}'$. By Proposition $9.23$ from Lemma $5^{\circ}$, we get
$$Jx^*J=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{{\omega}^{it-\frac{1}{2}}}{e^{\pi t} + e^{-\pi t}}{\Delta}^{-it}x'{\Delta}^{it}dt,$$
$$\text{hence } x^*=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{{\omega}^{it-\frac{1}{2}}}{e^{\pi t} + e^{-\pi t}}J{\Delta}^{-it}x'{\Delta}^{it}J dt,$$
$$\text{i.e. } x^*y'\xi_0=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{{\omega}^{it-\frac{1}{2}}}{e^{\pi t} + e^{-\pi t}}J{\Delta}^{-it}x'{\Delta}^{it}Jy'\xi_0 dt.$$
In contrast, by using the Corollary $9.23$,
$$x^*y'\xi_0=y'x^*\xi_0=y'Sx\xi_0=y'J{\Delta}^{1/2}(\Delta + \omega)^{-1}x'\xi_0=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{{\omega}^{it-\frac{1}{2}}}{e^{\pi t} + e^{-\pi t}}y'J{\Delta}^{-it}x'\xi_0 dt.$$
It follows that
$$F(\omega):=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{{\omega}^{it-\frac{1}{2}}}{e^{\pi t} + e^{-\pi t}}(J{\Delta}^{-it}x'{\Delta}^{it}Jy'\xi_0 - y'J{\Delta}^{-it}x'\xi_0) dt=0$$
for every $\omega\in\mathbb{C},\,|\omega|=1,\,\omega\neq -1$. Now I have the following problems.

**Problem 1:** The authors say that the above equality extends by analyticity to all $\omega\in\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0)$. I did not get this reasoning. How can I conclude that $F$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0)$?

**Problem 2:** Why is the function $t\mapsto \frac{1}{e^{\pi t} + e^{-\pi t}}(J{\Delta}^{-it}x'{\Delta}^{it}Jy'\xi_0 - y'J{\Delta}^{-it}x'\xi_0)$ an $L^1$ function?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Where are you looking at? In SZ, page 270, they work their formulas with $\lambda>0$ where you place the $\omega$.

Comment: I was following the 2019, 2nd edition of the book. There initially they work out the formulas with $\lambda >0$, and then work out those formulas for $\omega\in\mathbb{C},\,|\omega|=1,\,\omega\neq -1$ in the consecutive remark. But since only the formulas with $\omega$ were relevant for the final place where I got stuck in, so I just recalled those version.

Comment: I see, I didn't know there was a newer edition. I posted some arguments, probably not how they would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$
\|J{\Delta}^{-it}x'{\Delta}^{it}Jy'\xi_0 - y'J{\Delta}^{-it}x'\xi_0\|\leq 2\|x'\|\,\|y'\|\,\|\xi_0\|. 
$$
Then
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\Big\|\frac{1}{e^{\pi t} + e^{-\pi t}}(J{\Delta}^{-it}x'{\Delta}^{it}Jy'\xi_0 - y'J{\Delta}^{-it}x'\xi_0)\Big\|\,dt\leq\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{2\|x'\|\,\|y'\|\,\|\xi_0\|}{e^{\pi t}+e^{-\pi t}}\,dt<\infty,
$$
since
$t\mapsto \frac{1}{e^{\pi t} + e^{-\pi t}}$ is in $L^1(\mathbb R)$.

Then the function $F$ is defined for any complex number with argument other than $\pi$. Moreover, because the integrand is integrable, Dominated Convergence gives you that
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{F(\omega+h)-F(\omega)}h=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\big(-\tfrac12+it\big){\omega}^{it-\frac{3}{2}}}{e^{\pi t} + e^{-\pi t}}(J{\Delta}^{-it}x'{\Delta}^{it}Jy'\xi_0 - y'J{\Delta}^{-it}x'\xi_0) dt.
$$
So $F$ is analytic on $\mathbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$.

Comment: But it seems like $F$ is not even continuous at $0$. As for $\omega >0$, $|F(\omega)|\leq\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{|{\omega|}^{it}}{\sqrt{\omega}(e^{\pi t}+e^{-\pi t})}\|J{\Delta}^{-it}x'{\Delta}^{it}Jy'\xi_0 - y'J{\Delta}^{-it}x'\xi_0\| dt \leq \frac{2\|x'\|\cdot\|y'\|}{\sqrt{\omega}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{e^{\pi t}+e^{-\pi t}} dt$. So I think the authors meant to say that $F$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty, 0]$, and it will also be enough to conclude the final result. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I didn't even pay attention to that, but $F$ is not continuous at $0$.